# difference between an index and a value in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, indexing

I hear the two terms `index` and `value` used extensively in programming talk and know they mean different things. I'm confused, however as to what they exactly DO mean! And what the difference is....?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an array or a list like this:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
```

then

- 1 is the *index* of `b`
- `b` is the *value* at the index 1